# Setting the form value to an organic group gid from validation hook of custom field widget (Drupal 7)

Tags: 7, entities, organic-groups

I have a custom widget which can be used for a group audience field.  Instead of being a dropdown like the OG_AUDIENCE_WIDGET it is made up of three multiple select list, and the group which is actually selected is the one which is picked in the third select list.  I have the actual widget working but I am stuck on validation.  I have been trying to set the gid in a couple of different ways which have failed in a couple different manors.  First:

```
function multiselect_validate($element, &$form_state)
{
  if($form_state['submitted'])
  {
    $index = array_shift(array_values($element['wrapper']['dropdown_assignment']['#value']));
    $assignment_name = $element['wrapper']['dropdown_assignment']['#options'][$index];
    $query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $result = $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
    ->entityCondition('bundle', 'assignment_group')
    ->propertyCondition('title',$assignment_name)    
    ->execute();
    $node  = reset($result['node']);
    $assignment_gid = og_get_group("node", $node->nid)->gid;
    $value = $value[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['gid'] = $assignment_gid;
    form_set_value($element,array('gid'=>198), $form_state);
  }
}
```

This kind of validation returns an error:

```
[11-Dec-2012 11:23:07] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot unset string offsets in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/arcade/modules/field/field.default.inc on line 41
```

I also tried something like this for the final form_set_value:

```
form_set_value($element,array('gid'=>$assignment_gid), $form_state);
```

But when I do this and then look at the result nothing actually gets set into the field.

What is the proper way to set the gid for the field?

Comment: I wonder if there is a problem or something that is unclear about my question that is preventing people from answering it.  Does anyone have an advice about how I could reform my question to make it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the validate callback that you have mentioned in your question is the `#element_validate` callback for the field widget element.

In that case, `form_set_value` must be set to a *list* of items because a field is inherently *multi-valued*. Each item in this list must conform to the schema of the field.

So, in this case:

```
$items = array();
$delta = 0;
$gid = ...; // From somewhere
$items[$delta] = array(
  'gid' => $gid,
  'state' => OG_STATE_ACTIVE, // optional
  'created' => REQUEST_TIME - 3600 // optional (yesterday)
);
form_set_value($element, $items, $form_state);
```

To illustrate this better, I have a sandbox project up on drupal.org. It declares a new widget with hierarchical dropdowns just like you have described. You can check the code directly from http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/amarnus/1868742.git/tree/refs/heads/master or clone the project from http://drupal.org/sandbox/amarnus/1868742. Hope this helps!